# How do i use session authentication in a two-project Django application?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have a separate front & backend on the same domain, both in Django, for a user portal-style app. The front end has no database access. in my backend, I've set up a custom auth backend, using Django's session authentication, which works fine for logging in. but when trying to access request.user of a subsequent call from the frontend, request.user is an AnonymousUser. I'm guessing this is because the front end doesn't know about the current user, as it' done in the backend, so it's not included in the request.

How do i get session authentication to work, when there are two projects? Do i need some middleware to set request.user every time? Or store the session data as cookies instead of in the db?

Comment: When user login you need to store a token on client browser (localstorage or cookies)

Comment: @Florin so is there no point using session auth? is it better to use token auth instead and passing that token on every request?